# Linq To Sql Get data into Label 

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a label to show BookName. I get it from table which name tblBooks. I don't know how to show Book Name into the label.

`var query = from b in dc.tblBooks.Where(b=>b.BookID == 'B01') select b;`

Can you help me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your query as written will return a collection of books—`IQueryable<Book>`.  If you're sure there will only be one result in this query, you can call `SingleOrDefault`, which will execute the query immediately and give you the actual book.

```
var Book = dc.tblBooks.Where(b => b.BookID == 'B01').SingleOrDefault();
if (Book != null)
    myLabel.Text = Book.BookName;
```

Or you can simply say:

```
var Book = dc.tblBooks.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookID == 'B01');
```

Which does the same thing.

If you're 110% sure there will **always** be a result, and you don't want to check for null, then you can use `Single`, which will do the same thing, except throw an exception if no results are found, where SingleOrDefault simple returns null.

```
var Book = dc.tblBooks.Single(b=>b.BookID == 'B01');     
myLabel.Text = Book.BookName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
label.Text = query.FirstOrDefault().BookName;
```